# All tasks on a ECS service stuck in PROVISIONING state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to set up a service that launches 20 single-container tasks with an application load balancer. The problem is that every task stays stuck on `PROVISIONING`

The service has logged an error saying that "service service_name is unable to consistently start tasks successfully", which does not seem very helpful since the documentation basically explains that the task launch failed and there were many retries.

My cluster is using an AutoScaleGroup capacity provider whose launch template is using an ecs-enabled AMI, with a role that has AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role policy attached to it. The instance type is t2.micro (tried t2.small with no results)

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this situation? May the task definition be a cause for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start with a single task. Does it launch? Running 20 tasks on few t2.micro instances can be an issue, depending on how much cpu and ram they require.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end, I realized that each task must have an HTTP endpoint called /health that should return 200. By calling that endpoint, the load balancer determines whether the container is PROVISIONING or READY

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you did and where you did? Are talking about Endpoint in your code? or Somethings needs to be done in ECS service itself?

Comment: Yes, it should be an HTTP endpoint on each ECS container, coded by the developer.

Comment: load balancer uses health endpoint to detect the application's health state, it has nothing to do with the container. the container task might be up and running but eventually get terminated if health checks fail. can't see how the absence of health endpoint would make the task stuck in "provisioning" state. was it the same task all the time? maybe the tasks were constantly failing so you were thinking that it's the same task with "provisioning" state

Answer (score 5):

So, you need an IAM role attached policy ecsInstanceRole to the LC (Launch Configuration) to register the instance to the ecs cluster AND set the userdata to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=YOU_CLUSTER_NAME_HERE >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html

Comment: Don't use obscure abbreviations - what is an LC?

Comment: Launch Configuration

Answer (score 4):

In my case the task was stuck in PROVISIONING state because the task definition required 16GB memory, but the AutoScaleGruping EC2 instances had only 15GB available. I changed the memory in task definition to 15GB and I then I could start a task.

Comment: May I know how you find out about this?

Comment: The UI displays the memory available for the EC2 instances when you access the "infrastructure" tab of a cluster.